# Adding spaces inside words in list

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to add a " " () into words inside a list, but for some reason python doesnt let use ljust inside a list and it gives me this error:

> ' 'list' object has no attribute 'ljust''

My code:

```
spaced = []
sliced = ['text', 'text']
def spacer(sliced):
    for slice in sliced:
        print spacer
        # finds the word length
        lol = len(slice)
        lal = spaced.ljust(lol + 1)
        print lol
        spaced.append(slice)
        print spaced
```

What I need as output:
sliced = ['text ', 'text ']
Ideas on how to do would be apreciated! Thanks

Comment: What is spaced?  What is spacer?  I am not sure this is the exact code that gave you the error, spacer is defined as a function so this code is really confusing right now

Comment: @PyNEwbie, updated the code, (spaced) was a global array, so it wanst close to the usage function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) is a method for string. Use `slice.ljust(lol+1)`

```
sliced = ['text', 'text']
def spacer(sliced):
    result = []
    for slices in sliced:
        # finds the word length
        lol = len(slices)
        lal = slices.ljust(lol + 1)
        result.append(lal)
    return result

    #or you can you one-liner list comprehension instead of all of the above
    #return [word.ljust(len(word)+1) for word in sliced]

print spacer(sliced)
```

Instead of changing the list you are iterating over, create new one and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
 sliced = [word+' ' for word in sliced]
```

Answer (score 0):

quick solution:

```
def spacer(sliced):
    return [word+' ' for word in sliced]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
def spacer(sliced)
    return [x.ljust(len(x)+1) for x in sliced]
```

or more simply:

```
def spacer(sliced)
    return [x+' ' for x in sliced]
```

Using the method in your function you could do:

```
sliced = ['text', 'text']
def spacer(sliced):
    spaced = []
    for slice in sliced:
        lol = len(slice)
        lal = slice.ljust(lol + 1)
        spaced.append(lal)
    return spaced

print spacer(sliced)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a space to the end of a string is as simple as just using `+`:

```
string = 'a'
new_string = string + ' '
```

So you just need to iterate each item in your list and append the space:

```
for string in sliced:
    print string + ' '
```

So could just create a new list with a simple list comprehension

```
new_sliced = [slice + ' ' for slice in sliced]
```

Or alternatively, if you want to change the `sliced` list in place you could use the enumerate builtin to get the index of each element of your list

```
for i, slice in enumerate(sliced):

    sliced[i] = slice + ' '
```